# Can't connect with servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets, jakarta-ee

I've got the following ajax petition in Angular:

```
$scope.texto = "";
$scope.cargarDesdeBackend = function(){
    var nombre = "{'nombre':'Benito'}";
            $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/Datos',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      data:  nombre
    }).success(function (data) 
      {
        $scope.texto = data;
      });
  };
```

Notice that the "var nombre" line is just for testing purposes!

I send this petition from a button, and then it goes to the following servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try 
    {
      BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        sb.append(line);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject joUser = null;
    try
    {
      joUser = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    String user = (String) joUser.get("nombre");

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write("A new user " + user + " has been created.");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    }
```

This retrieves the following:

[image]

In the console, I get this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I've got this servlet mapped to "/Datos" in the web.xml file.

Comment: The client connects to the Servlet successfully BUT something wrong with your Servlet code so 500 status return. don't know how to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're sending is not valid JSON. Use

```
var nombre = {nombre: 'Benito'};
```

and let angular marshal this object to JSON.

Also remove the header which is useless, since Angular also adds it by itself.

Note that instead of reading the body line by line into a string and then parse the string, you should pass the reader to the JSON parser directly.

Finally, it would be much easier, for you and for us, to find what goes wrong by reading the stack trace of the exception, rather than trying to guess what the cause of this 500 error is.

Comment: You're right about the JSON thingy. I just realised this thing this morning in the shower, by the way #showerthoughts. Gotta check now if it works proper, otherwise let me paste the stack trace for the 500 error

Comment: Ok, this solved it. It seems that some error was happening with parsing the JSON (I guess) when it was wrong written. Now everything works great, thank you!